# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function in console window

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, datatable

I found this error on my console window, I doknow why this error come, I included datatable plugin correctly and here is my order

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/jquery.min.js') }}" ></script> 
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/bootstrap-select.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
<!--Custom-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/custom.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/upload.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/jquery.imgzoom.js') }}"></script>
```

Can any one please help me to fix this error... I am not sure the what the problem is ??

Comment: where is dataTables.min.css stylesheet?

Comment: can you see `/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js` successfully loading in browser developer tools network tab?

Comment: @diavolic - probably further up in the page `<head>` - clearly this isn't the full web page! And even if it were not loaded, it wouldn't cause the error :p

Comment: @Karthiga can Post entire page here?